# How do I check with an if statement what's inside two parentheses in Bash?

Tags: bash

I want to do a check to see what's inside a set of parentheses. For instance, say I have this

```
12($s0)
```

loaded into an array.

Now, I'd like to skip the start bit `12(` and last bit `)` and only check to see what the length of this is, `$s0`.

I don't want to cut the first and last bits out, just want to check what's in between.

How would I go about doing this in bash?

Comment: i've managed to figure out an alternative solution by using ${string: -4} to check the last four characters i.e. "$s0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a regular expression that captures what's between the parentheses, then check the length of that capture group:

```
$ str='12($s0)'
$ re='\(([^)]*)\)'
$ [[ $str =~ $re ]]
$ echo "${#BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
3
```

The regular expression uses literal parens at the start and the end (`\(...\)`); everything between them is in a capture group (`(...)`). The pattern being captured is "zero or more of any character that isn't a closing parenthesis": `[^)]*`.

When matching a regular expression with the `=~` operator, the capture groups are stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. Index 0 contains the complete match, indices 1 and up contain the capture groups. We're interested in the first one, and use the `#` in the expansion to get the length of the string.